# How can I build a graph from a file containing the traffic lines?

Tags: list, prolog, graph-theory

I'm struggling with my project in Prolog. My problem is, given a file containing the traffic lines in the form of `line(NameOfLine, Type, ListOfStations)`. For example:

```
line(m1, train, [a,b,c,d,e])
line(m2, train, [h,e,j,i])
...
```

where e is the intersecting station of two line (The real line file is very complicated and containing a dozen of lines with hundreds of stations). I have to do the classic graph question like find a routing, calculate the cost, etc.

I knew that I have to build a graph undirected before start, so I've tried something like this:

```
adjacent(X,Y,[X,Y|_]).
adjacent(X,Y,[_|T]) :- adjacent(X,Y,T).

find_edge(LArret) :- forall(adjacent(X, Y, LArret), assert(edge(X,Y))).

connected(X,Y) :- edge(X,Y) ; edge(Y,X).

graph :-
    forall(ligne(_,_,L),  find_edge(L)).
```

But I didn't get all the edges as expected. Can you guys give me some advice for that? Or was I wrong at very first for solving this kind of problem?

---

**Supplementary question:**
Thanks for the solution proposed and i've finally succeed to define the edges. Then i tried this algorithm classic to find a path betwwen A and B, but sometimes the search doesn't seem to end and sometimes the program stuck in searching.

```
connected(X,Y) :- edge(X,Y) ; edge(Y,X).

path(A,B,Path) :-
       travel(A,B,[A],Q), 
       reverse(Q,Path).

travel(A,B,P,[B|P]) :- 
       connected(A,B).
travel(A,B,Visited,Path) :-
       connected(A,C),           
       C \== B,
       \+member(C,Visited),
       travel(C,B,[C|Visited],Path).
```

I think the reason could be a loop in the graph or a infinite loop in seraching, how can I avoid this kind of problem but still find all the path possible?

Comment: I am not sure you need to construct any graph: The graph is defined by the already provided lists of stations for each line.

Comment: Boris, acctually what im tring to do is to create a pair of edge [a,b] which represents the edges of graph. If not doing so it will be difficult to find eg routing, am i woring at this point?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the following code with your `line/3` definitions to create your list of `edge/2` definitions:

```
adjacent(X,Y, [X,Y|_]).
adjacent(X,Y, [_|T]) :- adjacent(X,Y, T).

adjacent_lines(X,Y) :- line(_,_,L), adjacent(X,Y, L).

:- forall(adjacent_lines(X, Y), assert(edge(X, Y))).
```

It created all applicable and valid `edge/2` facts as specified by the `line/3` facts.
(at least, with SWI-Prolog)

Comment: Thanks for your inspiring comment, i will try it again.

Comment: Remember you can check for whether your `edge/2` facts exist with `bagof((X,Y), edge(X,Y), Ls).`